# Windows Identity Foundation on Windows 10 Tech Preview

Tags: wif, windows-10

I'm trying to install the Windows Identity Foundation runtime on Windows 10 tech preview and coming up short.

Under Windows 8/8.1 the WIF Runtime was available in the "Turn Windows Features On or Off" dialogue, but it's missing from there. Is there another way to get this installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if manual installation will be allowed, but here's a blog post from Feb 2015 that talks about WIF being replaced by OWIN for web developers in VS2015.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/25/identity-updates-for-web-developers-in-visual-studio-2015-ctp6.aspx

***Excerpt:*** *"from this CTP on, we no longer have any template using Windows Identity Foundation. We’re now fully on OWIN."*